# Rails Route Error Nested Routes (link_to user_post_path) 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested

Edit// Added an edit to the bottom. The issues seems to be linked to the user_post_path.

I tried typing:

```
<%= link_to 'show', user_post_path(post) %>
```

but get the error listed below before my edit.

Which led to:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :user_id=>#<Post id: 1, topic:
"1st Post", mood: "happy", post: "I don't know. Omg this works!", created_at: 
"2012-03-30   23:42:51", updated_at: "2012-04-01 06:01:48", user_id: 1>}
```

Ideas?

---

I've looked at the other posts related to this particular issue, but I've found no solution for my problem so far.

What I'm aiming for is to show a list of posts associated with a user. The rake routes says that /users/:user_id/posts should lead to the index file but strangely the error message refers to the :show action in the post controllers. Why? Also, why is the hash for :user_id empty?

All help is appreciated.

Here is my error in the browser:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :user_id=>#<Post id: 1, topic:
"1st Post", mood: "happy", post: "I don't know. Omg this works!", created_at: 
"2012-03-30   23:42:51", updated_at: "2012-04-01 06:01:48", user_id: 1>}
```

W

```
1 Testapp::Application.routes.draw do
2   resources :users do
3     resources :posts
4   end
5 
6   root to: 'home#index'
```

Here is my rake routes:

```
user_posts GET    /users/:user_id/posts(.:format)          posts#index
           POST   /users/:user_id/posts(.:format)          posts#create
new_user_post GET    /users/:user_id/posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_user_post GET    /users/:user_id/posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
user_post GET    /users/:user_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PUT    /users/:user_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /users/:user_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
      users GET    /users(.:format)                         users#index
           POST   /users(.:format)                         users#create
  new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                     users#new
 edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                users#edit
      user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#show
           PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#update
           DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                     users#destroy
      root        /                                        home#index
```

Posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.find_by_user_id(params[:user_id]) 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  # GET /posts/new.json
  def new
    @post = Post.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /posts/1
  # PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
   end

   # DELETE /posts/1
   # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Edit//

I scoped down the problem to a link_to.

```
14 <% @posts.each do |post| %>
15   <tr>
16     <td><%= post.topic %></td>
17     <td><%= post.mood %></td>
18     <td><%= post.post %></td>
19     <td><%= post.user_id %></td>
20     <td><%= link_to user_post_path(post) %>  #this is giving me an error
21   </tr>
22 <% end %>
23 </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these are nested paths, have you considered passing the User as well as the Post? Your final URL expects a `user_id` as well as a `post_id`, so you may need to call the following:

```
<%= link_to user_post_path(post.user, post) %>
```

The documentation is here: [Rails Guide on Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: I just was about to answer because I found the solution seconds before you answered!

Comment: This was my solution and it worked. <%= link_to 'show', user_post_path(post.user_id, post.id) %>

Comment: No worries - nested routes are tough that way. I generally try to avoid them. Good luck...