# How do I link to a post associated with a user (rails 4)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**First part:**

I have an index page that lists all the posts in my app. I want to be able to click on the links title and have it redirect me to the posts show page. Here is my index page.

```
<% provide(:title, "All Posts") %>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div>
        <h2><%= link_to post.title.titleize, post %> by <%= post.author.name.titleize %></h2>
        <div><%= post.body %></div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

When I try to go to my `index` page I get

```
undefined method `post_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc6df41ff98>:0x007fc6df436e78>
```

I pretty sure its because of the `post` in my link_to, but I dont know what I would put there to make it go to the right place. When I run `rake routes` it shows that the posts#show action is

```
user_post GET    /users/:user_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
```

so I tried replacing `post` with `user_post_path(post)` but then I get

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :user_id=>#<Post id: 4, title: "werwef", body: "erfwerfwerf", user_id: 3, created_at: "2013-08-16 20:05:43", updated_at: "2013-08-16 20:05:43">, :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

What should it be changed to?

**Second part:**

I have `<%= post.author.name.titleize %>` to print out the users name that posted the post, and Im getting it from a method I defined in my post model

```
def author
    User.find(self.user_id)
end
```

Is this the best way to do this? Before I made the method, I tried `post.user.name`, but that didn't work and just told me there was no method for `user` defined. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you set up the association with `belongs_to` and `has_many`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First Part**

Since these are nested paths, have you considered passing the User as well as the Post? Your final URL expects a `user_id` as well as a `post_id`, so you may need to call the following:

```
<%= link_to user_post_path(post.user, post) %>
```

The documentation is here: [Rails Guide on Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Extracted from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001371/rails-route-error-nested-routes-link-to-user-post-path).

**Second Part**

You might miss the association calls :

Post.rb

`belongs_to :user`

User.rb

`has_many :posts`

And then you can use `post.user`

Comment: Although implication might make it clear, I just want to explicitly point out that `/users/:user_id/posts/:id` has 2 parameters, `user_id` and `id`. The first parameter in your `user_post_path` will correspond to `user_id`, and the second to `id`. Rails will not infer this. Personally, when I run into these issues, I think about whether a more elegant approach exists where I don't need to nest the entire route. For example, perhaps you could do `resources :posts, :only => [:edit, :update]` or something of that nature. If you don't need the user ID, or could find it a different way maybe try it

Comment: @david - Would I need the user id for :new and :create too?

Comment: @oobie11 Anywhere you have two or more parameters in your routes, then you're going to need to pass that many in. Though, you should never have more than two. If you have more than two, it's a good idea to rethink your routing design. If your :new and :create also have :user_id and :id in the route, then you'll need the user_id for them.